# flutter countdown timer plugin not working, trying to set it to my own time but not working

Tags: flutter, dart

I found a flutter plugin for a count down timer but I can't seem to edit the time  property to my own time

here is the code for the plugin, it only works for this number 1576839556732 which sets the timer to two hundred days, I was trying  to set it to 10 minutes

```
child:CountdownTimer(
    endTime: 1576839556732,
    textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, color: Colors.black,fontFamily:"Clan-Medium"),
     onEnd: (){
   print("Game Over");
    },
        
         
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this package instead: https://pub.dev/packages/slide_countdown_clock

```
SlideCountdownClock(
          duration: Duration(days: 20, minutes: 1000000),
          slideDirection: SlideDirection.Up,
          separator: ":",
          textStyle: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
          shouldShowDay: true,
          onDone: () {
            _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Clock 1 finished')));
          },
        ),
```